# image flicker javascript on mouseover when using image maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using image maps to hover some images in a slider, works well but there is a flicker until it loads once, then it works well. Anyone knows why is this happening?

BY the way, it happens only in FIREFOX

```
<script>
    Image1 = new Image()
    Image1.src = "images/slide1aroll.jpg"
    function firstmap() {
        document.emp.src = Image1.src; 
        return true;
    }
</script>

<li style="width: 480px; height: 610px;"><img src="images/slide1a.jpg" name="emp" id="emp" class="emp" width="480" height="610" usemap="#model1" style="display:block; border:none;" border="0" /></li>
<map name="model1" id="model1" name="model1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="31,6,289,576" href="#" onmouseover="firstmap();" onmouseout="document.emp.src = 'images/slide1a.jpg';" alt=""/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="303,9,475,605" href="#" onmouseover="firstmap2();" onmouseout="document.emp.src = 'images/slide1a.jpg';" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do caching of the image

```
<div style="display: none">
    <img src="image1.png" />
    <img src="image2.png" />
    <img src="image3.png" />
</div>
```

With this you have all your image present at the first go. It will not flicker now. Try it

Comment: thank you, I did try an image preloader and it did not work, but this trick does, so.. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Image flickers because as soon as you hove over the image, you change the source of the image. Therefore, now your mouse is hovering over another image and not the one you intended.

As soon as the mouse comes over the newly loaded image, the new image gets hidden because your mouse is now not hovering over the older image. The moment it gets hidden, you mouse again comes over the older image and so the new image is once again visible.

The process continues giving a flickering effect. old image - new image - old image ....and so on

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thanks, but I think it hase something to do with preloading the images, if not there would be flickering everytime I move the mouse over the images. but as I said, it happens only the first time I hover, then until I reload the page it works fine